# Switching between a custom mobile display mode and desktop mode in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I would like to create a switch to full site link and switch to mobile link. I don't want to force it to go to either of them by using a session variable. I'd like to know if it's possible to do it automatically by using ViewSwitcher Controller.

Here is what I am using for my custom mobile display mode

```
 public class MobileDisplayMode : DefaultDisplayMode
{
        public static readonly List<string> MobileList = new List<string>
    {
        "Android",
        "Mobile",
        "Opera Mobi",
        "Samsung",
        "HTC",
        "Nokia",
        "Ericsson",
        "SonyEricsson",
        "iPhone"
        ,"ipod"
        , "symbian"
         ,"android"
                        ,"windows ce"
                        ,"blackberry"
                        ,"palm"
                        ,"opera mini"
    };

    public MobileDisplayMode()
        : base("Mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => IsMobile(context, context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()));
    }

    private bool IsMobile(HttpContextBase context, string useragentString)
    {
        return context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice || MobileList.Any(val => useragentString.IndexOf(val, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Here is my view switcher code - don't worry about IsMobile Property, it's handled the same way as mobile display mode

```
        if (IsMobile == mobile)
        {
            HttpContext.ClearOverriddenBrowser();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(mobile ? BrowserOverride.Mobile :                         BrowserOverride.Desktop);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery.Mobile.Mvc package to the project. A mobile layout will be created. Now every mobile view displays a link to the desktop version. Put the code below in desktop view, so the user can returns to mobile.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mobile view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { mobile = true, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { rel = "external" })
```