# MVC5 Mobile - Switch to desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application and I've implemented a number of mobile specific views. For example I have

- Home.cshtml
- Home.Mobile.cshtml

This approach works great as I have only the one action on the controller but I can shape the output specific to the device.

I would like to implement an override option to allow people to view the full version of the site, so effectively the Home.cshtml view is served instead of the .Mobile regardless of the client type. I have read up on this and all the articles I'm reading refer to installing packages etc which feels over the top to me given that the .Mobile approach worked out of the box?

Comment: How about using a session variable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620403/how-do-i-create-a-button-to-switch-between-mobile-and-desktop-modes-of-my-mvc-si?lq=1